# Postmates Invalide paramaters

Tags: python-requests, postmates

Getting some problems with this post request for creating a delivery:

```
{'dropoff_name': 'stephen', 
 'pickup_address': '1234 Bancroft Way, Emeryville, CA', 
 'pickup_phone_number': '1231231234', 
 'dropoff_phone_number': '1231231234', 
 'dropoff_address': '200 Powell Street, Emeryville, CA', 
 'pickup_name': 'ShareTea', 
 'manifest': 'boba'
}
```

Here's my code:

```
def post_data(self):

    post_data = {}

    post_data["manifest"] = self.manifest
    # post_data['manifest_items'] = self.manifest_items
    post_data.update(self.pickup.post_data("pickup"))
    post_data.update(self.dropoff.post_data("dropoff"))

    if self.quote:
      post_data["quote_id"] = self.quote.quote_id

    return post_data

def _make_request(self, url, data=None, type='get'):
    if type == 'post':
      print(data)
      headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      response = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=(self.api_key, ''), headers = headers)


params = delivery.post_data()
return self._make_request(url, data=params, type='post')
```

I'm getting a 400 Exception that says The parameters of your request were invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Does it identify which parameters are invalid?

If it's just the phone numbers, I had success by formatting the phone number in my request to the format of "123-123-1234'

Answer (score 0):

I believe the manifest field should be an array.